# Using ByRef variables in Windows Workflow Foundation?

Tags: .net, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

Lets say I create a simple workflow containing two variables, `result` of type `Boolean` and `myInt` of type `Integer`. Now add an activity "Assign", placing `result` in the result box, and `Integer.TryParse("22", myInt)` in the right hand expression.
After running this activity, the variable still has the value `0`.

Why is the result of the `TryParse` call not correctly stored in the variable? 
(No errors are generated here either)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how WF works. Variables don't have the concept of in/out as arguments. They don't implement implicit operators so the result will never be stored as you wish.

Either you implement your own TryParse activity or you can use [InvokeMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.statements.invokemethod.aspx) like this:

```
var resultVar = new Variable<bool>("result");
var myIntVar = new Variable<int>("myInt");

var activity = new Sequence
{
    Variables = 
    {
        resultVar,
        myIntVar
    },
    Activities =
    {
        new InvokeMethod
        {
            TargetType = typeof(int),
            MethodName = "TryParse",
            Result = new OutArgument<bool>(resultVar),
            Parameters = 
            {
                new InArgument<string>("22"),
                new OutArgument<int>(myIntVar)
            }
        },
        new WriteLine
        {
            Text = new VisualBasicValue<string>(@"""INT: "" & myInt")
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Okay, but how come an error is not generated somewhere along the line here? Some type of implicit conversion must be taking place somewhere?

Comment: @DeCaf: an error is not generated because it works as you configured it. It tried to parse it, it worked, and returned a value of true. The integer you passed in was copied, and the copy was actually successfully changed in its scope, but because you're not passing that value back by any means the one it was copied from (your variable) will never be changed.

Answer (score 1):

If you look under obj/x86/Debug or where ever your temp files are going in your project, you will find some intermediary .cs files that could satisfy your curiosity. I tried this out, and you get a class with a private int myInt and private bool result and a tryparse statement using those variables. Hence no blow up, though I did see some issues in my output window!